# What resampling method is used in gdal_merge?

Tags: python, gdal, interpolation, resampling, gdal-merge

I am using the gdal_merge [python script](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) to merge rasters that have slightly different, though similar, input resolutions. The documentation advertises that it can handle different resolutions, and in most cases, this works out reasonably well. However, I have had a few cases where the final merged raster looks significantly degraded, despite a relatively small resolution change (~10%). I first looked through the gdal_merge documentation to see if there were any options to set the interpolation method used to resample rasters whose resolutions change, but did not see anything. I then realized I do not even know what resampling method gdal_merge is using. How does gdal_merge handle resampling?

Also, if anyone has any thoughts on how to improve the results from using gdal_merge on rasters with different resolutions, I would be happy to hear those. I figured that would be a more challenging question though without providing many more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is nearest neighbor as written in http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2006-November/010619.html

There is also a hint in the mail "If you
want control over the resampling used, you should use gdalwarp instead."